# Android - extending ListActivity, ListView doesn't show up

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I want to create a ListView on separate activity (I hit button on my main and new activity with listview pops up) and I used this example as a template:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAX8R6UH8CY

i want to emphasize that it works fine when i do almost the same thing as in the video. Here's the sample:

```
public class ShowActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

    String[] shoplist = {"bread", "juice", "something"};

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shoplist));
}
}
```

But when i try to convert LinkedList (which i populate in the main activity) to String[] and then use it in the ArrayAdapter, the ListView doesn't show up (it doesn't crash - only empty activity is started). Here's the code:

```
public class ShowActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);


    String[] shoplist = new String[MainActivity.NameList.size()];
    for (int i=0;i<MainActivity.NameList.size();i++){
        shoplist[i]=MainActivity.NameList.get(i);
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, shoplist));
}
}
```

and here's my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buttons declaration 
    Button btnClickAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    btnClickAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnClickShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshow);
    btnClickShow.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnClickClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclear);
    btnClickClear.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/** On click actions */
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Declaration of text fields
    EditText nameField = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText valueField = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //checking which button has been selected
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnadd: {
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();   
        String price = valueField.getText().toString();

        if(name.length()==0 || price.length()==0) break;
        else {
            NameList.add(name);
            nameField.setText("");
            ValueList.add(Double.parseDouble(price));
            valueField.setText("");
        }
        break;
    }
    case R.id.btnshow: {
        //new activity...
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    case R.id.btnclear: {
        NameList.clear();
        ValueList.clear();
        break;
    }
    }
}

/** Instance variables */
//Lists declaration for data storage
public static LinkedList<String> NameList = new LinkedList<String>();
public static LinkedList<Double> ValueList = new LinkedList<Double>();

public static final String KLUCZ = "com.somethingsomething.ShopList.TEXT";
}
```

Anybody knows what's going on here? Thanks in advance for any help

---

PS here are the xml's, if someone needs them:
main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/name_"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/value_"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnshow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_all" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnclear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear_all" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ShowActivit" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Most likely your NameList is empty

Comment: Btw: in your ListView.xml the `.ShowActivit` is that a copy paste error?

Comment: @donfuxx i thought the same about NameList, but i don't know why - i first populate one or two "items" and then click on 'show all'

PS yes, it's a copy paste error, i have ".ShowActivity" in the program

Comment: Before calling setListAdapter: log the values of shoplist array to confirm that they are really empty

Comment: it's empty. 
I made an if statement to check this (i'm pretty new to android so i don't know how to 'log' things)

if (NameList.size()==0) setListAdapter creates predefined String[] ("bread", "juice", "something") 
else it creates NameList. 
And it created the listview with "bread..."

Comment: you can just use `System.out.println()` to output to the logs.